# Building multiple exe from one project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project from which I want to export multiple exe files (build the project multiple times). The way I do this is by running in a loop and every time changing the part in the project I want to be different and then building the project.

The problem I'm having is that when I build the project automatically the scene gets destroyed and I can't access the gameobject in it and edit them one I go through the loop again.

I tried to come up with a solution to this problem by loading the scene again but that didn't fix it.

What do you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you changing in your project, whats the use case here, as this might be a little XY'ish

Comment: Renaming labels/buttons and loading a different terrain

Answer (score 0):

As I know, editing and building at the same time is impossible.

Here is an idea:

1. Copy the whole project to another folder.
2. Open both 2 projects with 2 unity instances.
3. Every time you make some change, copy the file from the first project to the second one.
4. Run your auto build code in the second one.

Comment: I need to changed the scene after the build, then build again

Comment: Use PostProcessBuildAttribute, the document is just above PostProcessSceneAttribute. It notify you after the building complete.

Comment: But the loop doesn't repeat until the project finished building, I can see the process start again as soon as I have the exe

Comment: _"I can see the process start again"_, _"But the loop doesn't repeat"_, I'm confused. the loop and the build are different things?

Comment: Every iteration of the loop create a build. So when a loop ends I can see the exe that was created before the loop repeats

Comment: Yes, before the loop repeats, 1 build is generated, now you can change the scenes, then run the next build process. Is there any issue?

Comment: Do you want build them at the same time?

Comment: One after the other, every time I change something in the project and then I want to build it again

Comment: The thing is I don't edit while building, I edit, then I build